# Is it possible to lock the volume slider?

Tags: volume-control

I was wondering if there was anyway that I could lock the volume control for a user  because I have a computer hooked up to a sound system but if the computer does any amplification at all i.e. above 50% volume then it sounds distorted on the speakers. So I would like to lock in the computer volume at 50% for one if not all users at 50% and just use the control board its plugged into to control the volume.

And help would be awesome thanks.

Comment: Can you hook the sound system into the Line Out? It shouldn't be affected by volume controls like the regular speaker/headphone outputs.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it is possible to lock the Volume Slider, but the same effect of locking it at 50% can certainly be achieved.

Have a look at [this Answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/219925/114818) to a similar question which has been marked as 'Accepted' by its OP. According to this, to achieve the effect of capping the slider limit to 50%, we would use the value as `32768`.

So, we would set the sink level using the following command in a terminal:

`pacmd set-sink-volume <sink> <value>`

And replace `<value>` with `32768`; and `<sink>` with the sink name or sink index obtained from the following command:

`pacmd list-sinks`

This would achieve the effect of capping the volume slider at 50% (virtually).

Comment: This may cap it but it wouldn't prevent the volume from being lowered, correct?

Comment: Yes. We would be able to lower the volume as usual.