# How can the volume of a program be set to louder than 153%?

Tags: configuration, vlc, volume-control, pavucontrol

I'm dealing with a video that has very quiet but intact audio. I want to increase the volume of VLC a lot so that the audio can be heard. In `pavucontrol`, I can raise the volume of VLC from 100% to 153%, but I need it to be louder than this. How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to increase the 153% volume increase of `pavucontrol` but [this is a little complex](https://askubuntu.com/q/219739/57576) and not so easy to accomplish. Easier by far is to actually increase the volume available to vlc itself.

The *maximum possible* volume can be extracted from vlc by following these steps:

1. Open the vlc Preferences by first opening vlc and then pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
2. In 'Show Settings' select 'All'
3. Follow through:

   ```
   Main Interfaces > QT > Maximum Volume displayed
   ```
4. Set this value to 300 as demonstrated in this screenshot:

[image]

5. Turn your speaker volume up and enjoy the music :)

**Note:** See the new '300%' on the volume control at the bottom right:

[image]