# How do I disable 150% volume output?

Tags: sound, alsa

I've been searching high and low for an answer to this problem. We have a pc the controls the sound system in a community house and we've tried both Ubuntu and Mint, but both operating systems have the same problem. We can't prevent users from accessing the sound mixer and turn the volume up to 150%, which means that the speakers are being destroyed because of all the distortion.
Normal people use the USB volume knob that goes from 0-100%
Is there any way to get rid of this "amplification" and lock it at 0-100%? or simply password protect the mixer itself? Thanks

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/questions/219739/adjust-max-possible-volume-in-pulseaudio